# How to be informed of intermediate step on the server (process bar with ajax)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I want to process some algorith on 100 files wich are on the server. This will take some time. I will start that using an ajax call from the client side.
I would like to be informed on what is happening on the server side. I mean, to have a processing bar on the browser side that show where we are on the 100 steps of the server process.

do you know please, how to do that using ajax / Asp.Mvc ?

Thx

Comment: jquery progress bar is a good place to start.  Add an ajax call that you use to poll to get current progress to update the progress bar.

Comment: I Found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163393.aspx